# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) cv2

Tags: python

Hi all i having facing the above error while executing the code below.

```
img = cv2.imread('034.jpg',0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)
```

error as:

> File "bb.py", line 6, in 
>       contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2) ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 1):

As they are stated in [OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) you need another variable for unpacking cv2.findContours. For example;

```
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Comment: Thank you it works.